# There's a strange shadow on the skydome (Blender 2.8, Eevee)

Tags: shadows

[image: **enter image description here**]

First one is the skydome in other CG software however, in blender, there's a strange shadow. How can I fix it? [image]

Comment: I believe you mean the rounded/spherical light grey part visible in the background. While i would not call that a shadow, it stands out yes. Did you check in the MMD Display settings if there was something that could disable it?

Comment: I checked it,but there's nothing like that...